# The constructor does not exist

Tags: class, constructor, processing

I am trying to make a simple class for a pizza topping that can be dragged around with the mouse. When trying to implement this class, I get the error "the constructor "Toppings" does not exist." Despite the fact I created a constructor for the class. Below is the code for the class, and where the error message shows.

```
Toppings obj;

void setup()
{
 size(1000,1000);
 obj = new Toppings(); //this line has the error message
}
```

Below is the code for the Toppings class.

```
class Toppings
{
  //members
  int x, y, d;  //draggable circle position and size
  
 //Constructor
 Toppings(int x, int y, int d)
 {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.d = d;
 }
  
  //method
  void update()
  {
    if ( dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y) < d/2) { //mouse is inside the circle
      if (mousePressed) {         //mouse is inside the circle and clicked
        x = mouseX;    //change circle position to mouse position
        y = mouseY;
      } else {  //mouse is inside the circle but not clicked
      }
    }
    ellipse(x, y, d, d);
    fill(150, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I would expect this code to work just fine and register the constructor I set, but it doesn't. I've also found deleting the constructors entirely fixes the issue, but doing so creates issues later on in the program, which is why I've had to backtrack here to find another solution.

Comment: Can you go into more detail? I'm confused by what you mean David.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your constructor signature:

```
Toppings(int x, int y, int d)
```

And look at how you're using it:

```
new Toppings()
```

It's expecting 3 `int` values, and you're giving it 0 `int` values.  The error message could arguably be worded better, but it's indeed true that the constructor *you're trying to call* doesn't exist.

Either create a constructor with 0 parameters:

```
Toppings() { }
```

Or call the constructor with the parameters it expects:

```
new Toppings(0, 0, 0) // or whatever values you want to use
```